# Tensorflow: Concat different graphs for finetuning with external data

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to implement [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.03474) in tensorflow. It's approach is to create two separate CNNs at first, and then concatenate them for finetuning (as you can see in figure 1a)).

My current situation is: I have two pre-trained and saved models, each of them fed with a data queue input (so, no feed_dict and no Dataset API), and now i am off for finetuning. I want to restore them from disk and somehow concatenate them, so that i can define an optimizer which optimizes both networks.

This is my current approach:

```
# Build data input
    aug_img, is_img, it_img = finetuning_read_training_images(trainset_size=num_steps,
                                                              batch_size=batch_size,
                                                              cropped=cropped,
                                                              base_folder=base_folder)

    # Load the graphs
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    print("Loading ECNN graph...")
    ecnn_graph = tf.train.import_meta_graph(os.path.join(ecnn_path, "ecnn.meta"), clear_devices=True)
    trained_target = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("E-CNN/ecnn_output/ecnn_output_convolution/BiasAdd:0")
    augmented_icnn_input = tf.concat([is_img, trained_target], axis=2)
    icnn_graph = tf.train.import_meta_graph(os.path.join(icnn_path, "icnn.meta"), clear_devices=True, input_map={"aug_img": augmented_icnn_input, "it_img": it_img, "is_img": is_img})
```

The data input function reads 3 batches. `aug_img` is the source image, which has reflections, e.g. when photographed through a glass panel, augmented with its edge map as a 4th color channel. The ECNN graph should predict the reflection-free edge map. Tensorflow should augment the plain source image, which is stored in the `is_img` variable with the predicted reflection-free edge map, which should happen in the lines beginning with `trained_target` and `augmented_icnn_input`. The augmented image is then fed to the ICNN graph which should create a reflection-free image then, so it is given the `it_img` which is the target image. It is fed the not-augmented source image again, only for tensorboard visualization.

But now i am unable to further proceed. I cannot concat the both tensors for creating the `augmented_icnn_input` because i get a `ValueError: Tensor("E-CNN/ecnn_output/ecnn_output_convolution/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 224, 224, 1), dtype=float32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("batch:1", shape=(?, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32).`

Also i seem not to understand the input_map in combination with the data input queue correctly, since although i have had definied the  `aug_img`and other variables in the ICNN, and see them in tensorboard, i do not see them in the `variables` collection and therefore cannot map them.

So i would like to know: Is this the correct approach to combine two subgraphs in a bigger graph? How can i solve the problem that i am unable to concat the two tensors in `augmented_icnn_input`? And why is my `input_map` not working?